# My sql get data from multiple tables, comma separated

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, inner-join, resultset

I have 3 tables as follows
**Doctors**

```
CREATE TABLE `doctors` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_number` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `avatar_path` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `qualification` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `doctors_email_unique` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

**Specializations**

```
CREATE TABLE `specializations` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=105 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

and many-to-many of these 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE `doctor_specialization` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `doctor_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `specialization_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `doctor_specialization_doctor_id_foreign` (`doctor_id`),
  KEY `doctor_specialization_specialization_id_foreign` (`specialization_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `doctor_specialization_doctor_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`doctor_id`) REFERENCES `doctors` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `doctor_specialization_specialization_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`specialization_id`) REFERENCES `specializations` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Now I want the query to get the results from doctor with the specializations comma separated if more than 1.

Is there any way to achieve this in mysql way? Or I will have to do `php loops` on each result set?

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT(specializations) ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL Built-in function - [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT  d.first_name,
        d.last_name,
        GROUP_CONCAT(s.name) AS `specializations`
FROM    doctors d
        INNER JOIN doctor_specialization ds
            ON d.id = ds.doctor_id
        INNER JOIN specializations s
            ON ds.specialization_id = s.id
GROUP   BY d.first_name, d.last_name
```

Comment: By joining the tables, I loose the row that doesn't have specialization entered. Is there a way to get that row as well no value in specialization column?

Comment: Okay great, did it by using left join

Answer (score 0):

-- you should use somthing like INNER JOIN

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
```

ok now we go for use this syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM doctors
INNER JOIN doctor_specialization ON doctors.id = doctor_specialization.doctor_id;
```

you can use many as you need inner join on a statement. ie.

```
SELECT *
FROM doctors
INNER JOIN doctor_specialization ON doctors.id = doctor_specialization.doctor_id
INNER JOIN doctor_address ON doctors.id = doctor_address.doctor_id;
```